How to implement HSV-> Br/Cn -> RGB Curves shader pipeline in Godot 4?
I was developing a 3D asset in Blender and noticed that I can easily palette-swap its texture with this shader chain:

It produces great results and is very easy to readjust for millions of possible colours.
Problem is, Godot does not have node editor.
Is there a way to implement this chain in Godot 4.2.1? I'm using Forward+ renderer and shadeless default material.

Have you tried breaking this into parts, looking up first how to write an HSV conversion function in a shader, then how to write brightness/contrast, etc? You should be able to find existing examples of each, and the nodes already show how to string them together.
